# Active Audio Blend for Stereo Signal from single dual gang pot

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This is my attempt to create a blend between 2 audio sources. The image is for one of the 2 channels.

I am concerned this will not work, however I'm struggling to decipher why.

Will this work as i am expecting. Where the pot moved to full cw will only allow the main_out_L to pass and ccw will only allow cue_out_l to pass?

Comment: Make sure the pot is linear (A) and not log (B) !

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you show will blend the two input signals, with the blend portions dependent on the pot position.

However:

R17 and R20 are pointless.  I can't even guess what you think they accomplish.

The TL074 is a FET amp, so Vcc and Vee don't make much sense for power pin names.

Showing negative power at top and positive power at bottom is obnoxious, especially when you are asking others to look at your schematic as a favor.

The power pins seem to be shown twice for U9, at U9B n U9D.  Even more confusing, they are connected to something at U9D, but seem to be left open at U9B.

There are no bypass caps anywhere.

The actual power voltages are not shown.

Comment: My thinking behind R17 and R20 was that in a full turn position for the pot, the signal I dont wish to enter the final op amp stage will go to ground instead of being slightly present in the output. 

Apologies for informal annotation. This is simply a very small portion of a larger schematic.

Comment: Also, a bypass capacitor is simply between power rail and ground rail for response smoothing, correct?